# How do I get get clean URLs in twig templates

Tags: templating, url

When I use {{page.link}} or {{page.url}} in a template I am getting

http://mysite.dev/index.php?p=pages/about/history

when what I really want is

http://mysite.dev/pages/about/history

The latter URL works fine on the site, but I'm using the above code to try and create a menu, and don't want the menu item linking to the first URL.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documentation for removing index.php

http://buildwithcraft.com/help/remove-index.php

You might have to adjust the .htaccess code depending on your server.

Comment: Thanks for that. My .htaccess was fine, and the problem was immediately solved by adding `'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true,`
to the general.php file